# If the solution sets of two linear equations are equal, then the equations are identical.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Show that if the linear equations

$$x_1 +kx_2 = c \tag{1}$$

and

$$x_1+lx_2 = d \tag{2}$$

have the same solution set, then the equations are identical.

I attempted this beforehand, but a user pointed out a logical flaw with the proof. Here is my new attempt.

We wish to show that $c=d$ and $k=l$.

We note that the solution sets of each of the equations are nonempty, because we can find two points that satisfy their respective equations, as expressed below.

Clearly the point $(c-kc,c)$ satisfies $(1)$, and because the solution sets of the two equations are equal, it follows that this point also satisfies $(2)$. Substituting this point into the second equation, we have

$$d=c-kc+cl \tag{3}$$

Similarly, the point $(d-dl, d)$ satisfies $(1)$, so we substitute this point into the equation and solve for $d$ to get

$$d=c+dl-dk \tag{4}$$

Equating $(3)$ and $(4)$, we have

$$c-kc+cl = c+dl -dk $$

Simplification renders

$$(c-d)(l-k)=0$$

If $c=d$, then if $x_2\neq 0$, we have

$$x_1+kx_2 = x_1+lx_2$$

from which we deduce $k=l$, so the equations are identical.

Now if $k=l$, then for all $(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2$,

$$x_1 + kx_2 = x_1+lx_2$$

which implies that $c=d$. Hence the equations are identical.

Therefore for all $(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, the equations $x_1+kx_2 = c$ and $x_1+lx_2=d$ are identical whenever their respective solution sets are equal.

Answer (score 2):

A rough sketch of the proof:

Rewriting the equations as:

$$x_1 = -kx_2 + c$$
$$x_1 = -lx_2 + d$$

For $x_2 = 0$, (1) gives $x_1 = c$. The pair $(0,c)$ also satisfies (2):

$$c = 0 + d$$

$$\mathrm{or}\ c=d$$

Therefore

$$x_1+kx_2=x_1+lx_2$$
$$\mathrm{or}\ k=l$$

Since $k=l$ and $c=d$, the equations are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I will criticize your attempt as follows. The first two objections are minor while the third is more serious. Then I will show a similar but more stream-lined proof.

1. I think you meant to say that $(d-dl,d)$ satisfies $(2)$, not $(1)$.
2. immediately after that, you substitute into "the equation" without specifying which one. You want to substitute into the first one.
3. You correctly arrive at two cases, the first of which is $c=d$. But then you assume (without justification) that there is a solution for which $x_2\not=0.$

Here is a proof in the same style:

Let equation (1) be $x_1+kx_2=c$ with $S_1\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ its solution set. Let equation (2) be $x_1+\ell x_2=d$ with $S_2\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ its solution set.

We are given $S_1=S_2$, and we immediately note that this set is not empty, for $(c,0)$ belongs to it. Since $(c,0)\in S_2,$ $$c=c+\ell \cdot 0=d.$$ Hence all that remains is to show $k=\ell$. This follows easily once we note that $(c-k,1)\in S_1=S_2,$ so that $$c-k+\ell\cdot 1 = c.$$